# Why it is necessary that phase of incident, reflected and refracted wave must equal at the interface of two medium?

Tags: electromagnetism, reflection, refraction, boundary-conditions

1.Why it is necessary that phase of incident, reflected and  refracted wave must equal at the interface of two medium to satisfy the boundary conditions at the interface?
2. According to boundary conditions fields left to the interface must join fields right to interface why we just add amplitudes of fields E(I) + E (R) = E(T) here  E(I), E (R) and E(T) are amplitudes of incident,reflected and transmitted wave [image]

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing your level. Are you familiar the way to derive conditions on fields at boundaries using Maxwell's equations?

Comment: You may want to look into the Fresnel equations.

Comment: Prof.Andrew Steane my particular doubt is if according to boundary conditions fields left to the interface must join fields right to interface why we just add amplitudes of fields E(I) + E (R) = E(T) here  E(I), E (R) and E(T) are amplitudes of incident,reflected and transmitted wave

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary that the phase should be equal, as in the case of $v_2<v_1$, the reflected and incident wave is out of phase.

What is important that the field must satisfy the electrodynamic boundary conditions :
$$(1) \ \ \epsilon_1E_1^\perp=\epsilon_2E^\perp_2, \ \ \ \ \ (2) \ \ \ \ E^\parallel_1=E_2^\parallel$$
$$(3) \ \ \ B_1^\perp=B_2^\perp, \ \ \ \ \  \ (4) \ \ \ \  \ \frac{1}{\mu_1}B^\parallel_1=\frac{1}{\mu_2}B^\parallel_2$$
These equations relate the electric and magnetic fields just to the left and just to the right of the interface between two linear media.

The rest follows from here.

---

Additional Answer On Edited Question:

It's not necessary to use Amplitude, You can, if want to, use the fields. Suppose like as in Griffith, the fields are :
$$\mathbf{E}_I(z,t)=E_{0I}e^{i(k_1z-\omega t)}\hat{x}$$
$$\mathbf{E}_R(z,t)=E_{0R}e^{i(-k_1z-\omega t)}\hat{x}$$
$$\mathbf{E}_T(z,t)=E_{0T}e^{i(k_1z-\omega t)}\hat{x}$$

The interface is at $z=0$ so
$$\mathbf{E}_I(0,t)+\mathbf{E}_R(0,t)=\mathbf{E}_T(0,t)$$

$$\Rightarrow E_{0I}e^{i(k_1\cdot 0-\omega t)}+E_{0R}e^{i(-k_1\cdot 0-\omega t)}=E_{0T}e^{i(k_1\cdot 0-\omega t)}$$
$$E_{0I}+E_{0R}=E_{0T}$$
That's the same thing as to add amplitudes.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this point I think I just asked wrong questions pls review my edited question

Comment: See the edit and I don't think you have permission to add new questions through the edit, It's only for clarifying meaning or mistake. You can ask a separate questions.

Comment: Reflection occurs at a point and that can choose to be the origin. There is no loss of generality.

Comment: What happens in the case of oblique incident. Is this result still valid and if yes what about values of x and y they may not be zero ?This where the doubt of equality of phases came in my mind because this the only way exponential factor on both side cancel out and give the result u just derived

Comment: As I said, The reflection point occurs at a point in the reflection plane. You can choose it to be origin so that $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: I got your point my doubt is clear